# Optimizing .NET Core self-contained deployment

Tags: deployment, .net-core

I am developing a simple, cross-platform .NET application. I need to distribute it as a self-contained deployment as I can't assume if .NET is already installed.

.NET publish for Windows 10 64 bit generates a 64 MB directory. I am pretty sure most of the DLL files are not needed. Is there a way to optimize the distribution so that only the necessary DLL file are kept?

Comment: side note: if you should be using .net core 2.0, use `win-x64` over `win10-x64`

Comment: thanks. makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

I'm facing the same problem. So far, here's what I found:

Microsoft released a [Trim tool](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/Microsoft.Packaging.Tools.Trimming/docs/trimming.md) that finds unused assemblies and removes them.

With .NET CLI:

- `dotnet add package Microsoft.Packaging.Tools.Trimming -v 1.1.0-preview1-25818-01`
- `dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c release /p:TrimUnusedDependencies=true`

Your application's footprint is now much smaller (normally)

---

For a better optimization you can use it with ILLinker:

- `dotnet new nuget`

Open nuget.config and add `<add key="dotnet-core" value="https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json" />`between `<packageSource>`

[Here](http://pasted.co/19ce4ccd) is an example of what your nuget.config should look like.

Then execute the following commands:

- `dotnet add package ILLink.Tasks -v 0.1.4-preview-981901`
- `dotnet add package Microsoft.Packaging.Tools.Trimming -v 1.1.0-preview1-25818-01`
- `dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c release /p:TrimUnusedDependencies=true`

Using these two tools I managed to divide the size of my application by three.

Source: *[Reducing the size of self-contained .NET Core applications](https://ianqvist.blogspot.fr/2018/01/reducing-size-of-self-contained-net.html#comment-form)*

---

I'm still trying to get better optimization. I want to run my ASP.NET Core application (currently 72 MB) in an embedded system with only 10 MB.

If anyone has found a better optimization, I'm a buyer.

Answer (score 3):

Since .NET Core 3.0, it's as simple as adding a flag to your project's `.csproj` file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>

  <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed> <!-- Add this flag to enable trimming -->
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then you can just use `dotnet publish` to generate a trimmed executable.

And here's a warning from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0):

> It's important to consider that applications or frameworks (including
> ASP.NET Core and WPF) that use reflection or related dynamic features,
> will often break when trimmed. This breakage occurs because the linker
> doesn't know about this dynamic behavior and can't determine which
> framework types are required for reflection. The IL Linker tool can be
> configured to be aware of this scenario.
>
> Above all else, be sure to test your app after trimming.

A typical reduction result for a simple console applications seems to be from about **70 MB** to about **28 MB**.

Answer (score 2):

Update 2020: This is now part of the toolchain, see Pawel's answer.

This task can be done by using the IL linker. By adding a NuGet package to your project it can reduce the size of the published self-contained application by removing code that is not needed. However, it is still in preview (as of 2017). See the [announcement post](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/30) and [sample instructions](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/linker-instructions.md) for self-contained applications.

Comment: That's impressive :-) The deployment size got reduced by 50% as the page claims. Very promising but I am not sure I could use this for production use yet. 

Still boggles my mind I need 32MB for a simple app that interfaces with stdin/stdout, json with newtonsoft and outputs logs with Serilog. Similar app in Python got frozen to 10MB.  I am sure this could be apples and oranges comparison.

I will follow this linker's progress closely as it could be crucial for micro-services

Comment: @PeterMortensen you're right. Answers like that are hard as things are changing.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft.DotNet.ILCompiler](https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/dotnet-core/package/nuget/Microsoft.DotNet.ILCompiler) seems to be an even better option than ILLinker. [See this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44835273/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-console-application-run-using-only-a-single-file-in-ne/53743869#53743869).

My testing of .NET Core 2.2 self-contained outputs on the same source code gave:

1. Default self-contained publish: 68 MB
2. ILLinker: 36 MB
3. ILCompiler: 5 MB