# How to publish only required dependencies?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

If I create a "Hello World" .NET Core C# Console application in Visual Studio 2017 and run

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64 --self-contained
```

The resulting `publish` folder has 215 files in it, totals 62MB and includes the whole of .NET, which the application doesn't use. For example, it has `System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.dll`.

This is part of the "Microsoft.NETCore.App" dependency which I seem to have no way to edit manually. How can I trim that down to what the application is actually using?

Comment: See: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/linker-instructions.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [deployment documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/):

> Unlike FDD, a self-contained deployment (SCD) doesn't rely on the presence of shared components on the target system. All components, **including both the .NET Core libraries and the .NET Core runtime**, are included with the application
>
> (emphasis mine)

If you don't want to deploy the whole .NET Core runtime along with your application, then you should use a [Framework-dependent Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#framework-dependent-deployments-fdd) (FDD) instead of a [Self-contained Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd) (SCD).

```
dotnet publish -c Release
```

---

In the future, the [CoreRT runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/corert) – which is still under development at the time of writing  – aims to allow creating a single pre-compiled native executable that is specific to a runtime and does not require any other files.

Reference: [Is there a way to make a console application run using only a single file in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44835273/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-console-application-run-using-only-a-single-file-in-ne)

Comment: I'm not talking about the runtime but the unnecessary framework DLLs like the one I mentioned in the post.

Comment: Since `Microsoft.NETCore.App` depends on them, you need them. I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44840894) and while Microsoft is making a [CoreRT runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/corert) to make a single deployment file in the future, it is still a work in progress.

Comment: Is there any way to publish a Windows Service written in core 2.0 in FDD flavor? I am stuck here as 3 microservices take 310mb storage on my host - ridiculous, I am about to ditch core development!

Comment: I had the same confusing (why are so much dll's copied to the publish-folder) so thanks for both - the meaningful question and also answer. So I go with Self-contained Deployment for now as I don't have to install the runtime separately on the server and have the full control to my app environment this way.

Answer (score 3):

There is a 3rd option as well: "[Framework-dependent executables (FDE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#framework-dependent-executables-fde)"

You need to use `--self-contained false` e.g.:

```
dotnet publish <xyz.csproj> -c Release -r win-x64 --self-contained false
```

The 'Publish' folder still contains some Microsoft.*.dlls. However way less. In my case previous **publish was folder size was 84MB now it is 12MB only!**