# How to run dotnet core app from command line?

Tags: c#, .net-core, command-line-interface

I created a CLI tool using dotnet core framwork and I want to run it form the console as:

```
$ candyapp --arg1 some-value
```

I run it now by going to the location where the dll file is by uing:

```
$ dotnet candyapp.dll candyapp --arg1
```

Can anyone help me install my application and use it on my mac?

Comment: You can’t, but you could wrap it into a shell-script.

Answer (score 6):

Use the run command line args of the dotnet app.

```
dotnet run [-c|--configuration] [-f|--framework] [--force] [--launch-profile] [--no-build] [--no-dependencies] [--no-launch-profile] [--no-restore] [-p|--project] [--runtime] [[--] [application arguments]]
```

For more info, please see [dotnet cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run?tabs=netcore2x)

Comment: Also, this uses the`dotnet` command I wanted to run the app without it like any command line app

Comment: take a look at my previos answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53349046/1179843